# Calculating the average of a list in Python 3

Tags: python, class, methods

I am currently trying to calculate the average of a list created by a method in a class.  Firstly all information is passed to a Class that records/returns the data passed through from the main function.  The issue is what do I pass in from the main function to firstly retrieve the self._marks list and then manipulate it in order for the average to be returned.  Also am I using the correct code for the calculateAverageMark section?  Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
class Student :
    def __init__(self, id):
        self._studentId = id
        self._marks = []
    ##
    # Converts the student to a string .
    # @return The string representation .
    #

    # Sets the student's ID.
    # @param newId is the student's new ID.
    #
    def setStudentId(self, id):
        self._studentId = id

    ##
    # Gets the student's ID.
    # @return the student's ID
    #
    def getStudentId(self, newId):
        return self._newId

    ##
    # Appends a mark to the marks list
    #
    def addMark(self, mark):
        self._marks.append(mark)

    def __repr__(self) :
        # Build a string starting with the student ID
        # followed by the details of each mark .
        s = "Student ID :" + self._studentId + " "
        if len(self._marks) == 0 :
            s += " <none \n>"
        else :
            for mark in self._marks :
                s += " Course Module: " + mark.getModule() + " Raw Mark: " + str(mark.getRawMark())

        return s

    ##
    # Method to calculate the students average mark
    #
    def calculateAverageMark(self):
        totalMarks = 0
        count = 0
        for mark in self._marks :
            if mark == 0 :
                count = count
            else :
                count = count + 1

            totalMarks = totalMarks + mark
            average = totalMarks / count

        return average
```

Comment: Watch out for divide-by-zero...

Answer (score 4):

Your current code is incorrect because you divide by `count` in every iteration (and before `count` is actually the number of marks). Calculating the average is very easy with a list of values:

```
def calculateAverageMark(self):
    if self._marks: # avoid error on empty list
        return sum(self._marks) / float(len(self._marks))
```

You don't need to pass anything in; all instance attributes are available via `self`. Unless you have specifically been told to exclude zero scores from the average, you should count them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, we have been told > Note: Beware of division by zero errors (when there are no marks associated with a student) when dealing with calculating the average of marks

Comment: That is when the list is empty (hence the test `if self._marks`), not if there are zero scores